# No Sympy two-sided limits?

Tags: python, sympy

I can't get Sympy to handle two-sided limits.  Running in a Jupyter notebook, Anaconda installation:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
limit(1/x,x,0)
```

gives an answer of `oo`.  Furthermore,

```
Limit(1/x,x,0)
```

prints as a right-sided limit.  In fact, all of my two-sided limits 'pretty-print' as right-sided limits.  They seem to be evaluated that way, too. Can't find a way to force two-sided.  Of course, one could write a short program to remedy this.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The docstring of `sympy.limit` states that the (optional) argument `dir` can be used to specify the limit direction (either `"+"` or `"-"`). By default, it is set to `"+"`.

Comment: Thanks.  The documentation at http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/calculus.html  states that "To evaluate a limit at one side only, pass '+' or '-' as a third argument to limit. "  As mentioned in the answer below by @asmeurer, it's actually the fourth argument!  Nevertheless, it gives you incorrect answers mathematically.  Strange, given how easy this is to fix.

Answer (score 1):

`limit` has a fourth argument, `dir`, which specifies a direction:

```
>>> limit(1/x, x, 0, '+')
oo
>>> limit(1/x, x, 0, '-')
-oo
>>> limit(1/x, x, 0)
oo
```

The default is from the right. Bidirectional limits are not directly implemented yet, but you can easily check both directions.

Comment: Thanks!  Responded to similar comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Two sided limits are now directly implemented.

```
>>> limit(1/x**2, x, 0, '+-')
oo
```