# Resolving the existence of two sided limits

Tags: python, sympy

I do not know what this error is due to, according to the other users I should have an error as the limit does not exist, however, it gives me another, I have the latest version of sympy

```
x = Symbol('x')
a=Limit((5-x)/(x-2), x, 2,"+").doit()
print(a)
b=limit((5-x) / (x-2), x, 2, "+-")
print(b)
c=Limit((5-x)/(x-2), x, 2,dir="+-").doit()
print(c)
"direction must be either '+' or '-', not %s" % dir)
ValueError: direction must be either '+' or '-', not +-
```

Comment: It seems like sympy doesn't have bidirectional limits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672198/no-sympy-two-sided-limits

Comment: If you want the bidirectional limit you can calculate both one-sided limits and check if they are equal

Comment: thanks amiller27 I think that is the solution and I had not seen that functionality was not implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `dir="+-"` is implemented in the current development version of SymPy, which you can get by [cloning from its GitHub repo](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/).

It is not implemented in 1.1.1, which is the current release. It will be in 1.2, next SymPy release.